# Can I use my netgear router like a "mini" DNS server?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I have a netgear router and I want to host a local website on that wifi network. I want anybody connected from a laptop or mobile phone to be able to type "mylocalwebsite.com" in the web browser and be redirected to the ip of the server where the website is hosted. Currently the only way I can access the website is by manually typing the ip address of the server, but I want people to visit my website by typing a more user friendly name. Can I do this just by using my router or do I need to set up a DNS server? Or is there another way?

Comment: This depends on the model of the router, whether the feature is there. If it isn't, then the next option is to run DNS/DHCP from the webserver.

Comment: it's a NETGEAR WG302

Answer (score 0):

May be depending on the model, but for most you could manually point it in the DNS settings on the router.
[See this KB.](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/21928/~/how-do-i-manually-add-a-host-name-and-an-ip-address-using-the-web-interface-on)

It's worth nothing in all likelihood they could use the hostname of the server in most conventional network environments too. Hostnames are usually prettier than IP addresses?

Comment: It's a NETGEAR WG302. Your link talks about a "managed switch", I don't think I have that. I tried to change my computer name to "mylocalwebsite.com" but it doens't allow dots.

Comment: Whoops my bad. I don't see the option in the WG302 but it's an option in a lot of residential router's admin interfaces. Worst comes to worst you could host a DNS server as well and point it to that as your primary DNS server, but that's messy IMHO.

Comment: @agugglez Do you see an option in the WG302 config (at your admin page, probably 192.168.1.1 or whatever your internal address is) for manual DNS entries? A managed switch is honestly very similar to a router in a few ways. Many managed switches can even be dumber than routers.